# Angular typescript

Tags: angular, rest, typescript

i am new to both Angular 2 and typescript.

This is my track component where i get track from api.

```
    import { Component, ViewEncapsulation, OnInit, OnDestroy } from 
      '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

import * as moment from 'moment';


import { TrackService } from './track.service';
import { Track } from './track.model';
import { Response } from '@angular/http';


@Component({
    selector: 'da-article',
    templateUrl: './track.html',
    styleUrls: ['./track.scss'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated,
    providers: [TrackService]
})
export class TrackComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    private track: Track;
    private error: Response;
    private isLoading: boolean = true;
    private releasedTrack: string = moment("2013-03-10T02:00:00Z").format('DD-MM-YYYY');
    private duration: string = moment(345678).format("m:ss");


    constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private trackService: TrackService
        ) {

    }


    ngOnInit(): void {
        let TrackId = this.route.snapshot.params['trackId'];

        this.trackService.getAll().subscribe(
            (data)  => this.track = data[TrackId],
            (error) => this.error = error,
            ()      => this.isLoading = false
            );

    }


    ngOnDestroy(): void {}
}
```

In these lines

private releasedTrack: string = moment("2013-03-10T02:00:00Z").format('DD-MM-YYYY');
    private duration: string = moment(345678).format("m:ss");

I want to pass {this.track } instead of hardcoded value.

This.track is undefined, (as it is not available)

how can i achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Indeed, `this.track` isn't available at object construction time. You have to do it later in `ngOnInit` when `this.track` becomes available.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like `this.track` is initialised in ngOnInit(). It seems to me that the solutions is just to pass `this.track` after its initialisation in ngOninit(). I assume in the following manner:

```
this.trackService.getAll().subscribe(
        (data)  => this.track = data[TrackId],
        (error) => this.error = error,
        ()      => this.isLoading = false,
        ()      => this.track //it should now have value different from undefined
        );
```

Hope this helps :)

Edit:

To explain further, the initialisation of your releasedTrack variable happens before ngOnInit(), ie before the app has fully loaded. On top of that, you are calling a service `this.trackService.getAll()`, which returns a promise. This means that the method is going to execute asynchronously and does not guarantee that it will finish before the line after that is executed. Example:

```
this.trackService.getAll().subscribe(
                   ...
        )
this.track; // this might be undefined, since this.trackService.getAll() might not have finished
```

That is why you use the .subscribe method to define functions which are to be executed after the .getAll() method finished. Namely, you define the so called arrow functions in the format `(variable) => action`, where variable is the return value of the previously executed function.

Comment: Thanks @sapit ! but this is still unavailable

Comment: @Spdexter I am curious why you chose to use subscription, instead of .then() ? It may be just that I am inexperienced, but when I was using services, however, both the Angular2 and Angular4 tutorials suggested you use a promise and then invoke .then()

Check here: [Angular2 Service](https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html)

Comment: i will try promises as u suggested. i am using Observable in my service

Answer (score 1):

So i figured how to use oncomplete after the observable has completed.
The subscribe function takes three parameters: 
onNext 
onError 
onCompleted

I rewrote to this:

```
 public getDuration(){
    return moment(this.track.trackTimeMillis).format("mm:ss");
}


public getReleaseDate(){
    return moment(this.track.releaseDate).format("DD-MM-YYYY");
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    let TrackId = this.route.snapshot.params['trackId'];

    this.trackService.get(TrackId).subscribe(
        (data)  => this.track = data,
        (error) => this.error = error,
        () => {  this.duration = this.getDuration(),
            this.releasedDate = this.getReleaseDate(),
            this.isLoading =false},

            );

    this.chooseRandomTracks();

}
```

and it works!

Answer (score 0):

Try flatMap operator if you plan send data from one observable to the other